# Bose® MIE2i mobile headset 's volume control stopped working with IOS8

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, sound-volume, headphones

Bose® MIE2i mobile headset worked great with my iPod Touch since iOS7.. for last one month. After I upgraded to iOS8, it stopped working (Volume control).

But I tested with my iMac, it still works as expected. It doesn't make sense to me. A software upgrade impacts this? I have raised a complaint to bose as well. Just curious, it took 9.3K indian rupees for me!

**Update:** [Looks like am not the only one impacted! - Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/message/26626324#26626324)

Comment: Dose it show up in your Sound preferences? Or is it only the volume control not working but the speakers are?

Comment: Just the volume control. The speakers are perfect.

Comment: The remote and mic are supported only by iPod nano® (4th, 5th, 6th and 7th generations); iPod classic® (120GB, 160GB only); iPod touch® (2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th generations); iPhone® 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPhone 5C and iPhone 5S; all iPad® models; and MacBook® (unibody) and MacBook Pro. The remote is supported by iPod shuffle® (3rd and 4th generation). Audio is supported by all iPod® models. Requires latest iPod software.--> and you have one of those ?

Comment: Buscar, it was working till yesterday.Then i updated to iOS8.. Mine is iPod Touch 5th generation. Still the headphone's remote work with my iMac..

Comment: Yes, I know that, the question is if the iOS 8 recognizes it.

Comment: It doesn't.. no response to any of the keys.. Speakers are good though.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I seriously doubt if it is a software issue. Anyway going to Apple store tomorrow.. The warranty period is void.. :( I was loving the remote, so much.. Suddenly I lost it!

Comment: do you have another one to try

Comment: I have other brand normal stereo headphones. But not bose/apple with mic and remote. It has something to do with iOS8 or my Headphone port?

Comment: Just spoke online with they support, they say it is the iOS 8, so have to wait till Apple fixes it.

Comment: OMG !! You mean support from Apple?

Comment: NOPE I mean the Bose people :(

Comment: Aahh.. So it is a confirmed bug..? Atleast I trust Apple, they might fix. Concerned, if I have something to do to my headphone port.!

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have friends too it seems on this issue!! [From Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/message/26626324#26626324)

Answer (score 1):

So far we concluded it is a iOS- 8 issue.

My online chat with Bose support came with same result, it is not a Bose problem.

It is not officially confirmed by Apple, but sure they are working on a fix already.